# Translate Twilio audio Stream from webRTC to text realtime?

Tags: webrtc, twilio, speech-recognition, voip, voice-recognition

I need to get the twilio voip audio signals from a phone number and convert the audio to text in realtime without disconnecting the call to take specific actions.

[1. call voice] -> [2. convert to text #realtime] -> [3. detect voice end] -> [4. get final string]

How can this be done without disconnecting the call?

I looked into translator.js, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As you've probably deciphered based upon your translator.js suggestion above, Twilio `Recordings` do not handle this. Even with a way to [`transcribe` calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe) it will not do so in real time as you are hoping for.

With a quick search, one thing that looks pretty cool and might be helpful in your use case is the [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API).

If you check it out, do let me know if it helps!